# can't load the Doctrine libriles and PDO drivers

Tags: doctrine, pdo, php

I'm using Win 7, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.4.
I want to add doctrine lib and PDO to my local server.

- PHP install path: `C:\php\`
- doctrine lib path: `C:\php\extras\doctrine-dbal`
- PDO drivers path: `C:\php\ext`
- Apache2.2 path: `C:\Apache`

**php.ini**

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\php\extras;C:\php\extras\doctrine-dbal"
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

**phpinfo() image**

[image: PDO drivers]

[image: Include path]

web app give below error

```
Warning: require_once(Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache\htdocs\stack\UMS\classes\class.dbextractor.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Apache\htdocs\stack\UMS\classes\class.dbextractor.php on line 2
```

how can i change the include path for doctrine and PDO drivers in php.ini file

Comment: php.ini file include path and phpinfo() include path is deference please any one can tell reason for this